# Can I implement workflows in Sharepoint without Desginer?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I need to know if there´s a chance to do a workflow on SP without using SP Designer. I am kind of new on these SP technologies and I will want to know if there´s a chance to do it.

Comment: You need to give us the more information, what kind of the workflow you want to create? their are OOTB workflows which can be configured without designer.

Comment: Actually I haven't so much experience on SP but I will try to explain you what we want to create. We want to create an approval workflow that has 2 approvers at least. We have no idea if we can do that workflow on SP directly(without Designer) and link it to a list/library. We are not able to use InfoPath forms either and we really need to know if there's a chance to don't make workflows only via SP Designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your explanation:

Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 includes several approval workflows that you can begin using right away to manage human workflows in your organization. Each workflow can be added to a list, library, or content type and then used by your business users to manage the items or documents in the associated lists or libraries.
here are default workflow avaible in SharePoint server:

> approvals, collect feedback, collect signatures, manage publishing of
> assets, manage dispositions, create three-state approvals and Disposition Approval.

You can read more about the OOTB workflow [on this post](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/understand-approval-workflows-in-sharepoint-2010-HA101857172.aspx). You can use the **Approval workflow** to achieve this goal.

http://www.tipsandtutorials.net/create-approval-workflows-sharepoint-server-2010.html

Also check this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzXtp996ciA

Comment: Very useful information about workflows, that was I wanted to know about these workflows. Thank you very much Waqas.

Comment: If Wasqas answered your question, you should accept his answer. SE works best when volunteers who provide answers get acknowledged/rewarded.